# Conditionally building an Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

**The Context**

I'm using Laravel's [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) as my ORM.  I am creating an API endpoint which provides access to `Cars` which have several attributes (`color`, `make`, `status`).

My endpoint allows clients to filter the return value by any subset of those attributes, if they provide no attributes then I will return everything.

**The Question**

I want to build a conditional query, which starts from "all" and narrows down based on which parameters have been specified.  Here's what I've written:

```
public function getCars(Request $request)
{
    $results = Cars::all();

    if($request->has('color'))
         $results = $results->where('color', $request->input('color'));

    if($request->has('make'))
         $results = $results->where('make', $request->input('make'));

    if($request->has('status'))
         $results = $results->where('status', $request->input('status'));

    return $results->toJson();
}
```

If I call this with no parameters the API returns a list of all cars in the database.
If, however, I specify (for instance) status of `0` the API returns an empty set, despite the fact that some cars have status of `0`.

Am I approaching this incorrectly?  Is there something fundamental I'm missing?

Note that if instead I write:

```
$results = Cars::where('status', 0);
return $results->get();
```

The list of cars is properly generated

Comment: Are you sure `$request->input('status')` is equal to 0 and received like that from frontend and not in different format like string?

Comment: Great question -- yes, I edited out the input validation for the sake of the question.

Comment: you get results for `$results->get()` because it actually returns a collection, while your `$results->toJson()` actually an [eloquent builder instance](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html). before you blame the client, try to `dd($results)` first to be sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change your function like this:

```
public function getCars(Request $request)
{
    $results = Cars::query();

    if($request->has('color'))
         $results = $results->where('color', $request->input('color'));

    if($request->has('make'))
         $results = $results->where('make', $request->input('make'));

    if($request->has('status'))
         $results = $results->where('status', $request->input('status'));

    return $results->get()->toJson();
}
```

Comment: Oh perfect!  Thank you.  On a related note is there a better resource for documentation than the one I linked to?  I don't see any mention of query() in there!

Comment: the `query()` comes from [model instance](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html). better to read the api and source code to learn more :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this, for simplicity.

```
$query = Cars::query(); // no query executed, just give us a builder

$query->where(array_only($request->all(), ['color', 'make', 'status'])); // where can take a key value array to use
// update: only taking the vars you need, never trust incoming data

return $query->get(); // will be converted to Json for you
```

This only queries the DB for what you need. Yours is returning all results then filtering through them in a collection.

Update:
As Joseph stated, there is different functionality between $request->only() and array_only. The functionality of array_only is wanted here.

Comment: For this particular example, I think this method is cleaner than doing a bunch of `has` checks manually. You could also inline this to `return Cars::where($request->all())->get();`

Comment: Yea, I just broke it up to make the $query builder part stand out. To show you can use it that way.

Comment: this method looks like cleaner, but somehow, i fear we could practically get everything within the database.

Comment: idk what you mean about that, but this is a simple example. You should not use $request->all() passed to it. You should only take the inputs you need so no one can pass extra fields that will break the query.

Comment: Don't use `$request->only`. It'll return `null` for keys not present in the request, which is definitely not what you want. Use `array_only($request->all(), [....])` instead.

Comment: good call Joseph, thats what i get for testing with array_only instead of request only